# How should my OSX App store the user's private key?

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, keychain

I'm building an app that uses RSA asymmetric key encryption.

The public key is sent to our API but the private key needs to be stored securely on the user's computer.

One option would be to follow the same pattern as SSH and store the key on disk (with the permission locked down to 0600 / `rw----`).

Would this be a good fit for the OSX keychain?
If so how would you store the key? Most Cocoa wrappers for the C API I've seen are very password-centric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **login** keychain suits well for your app, for at least the following reasons:
1. it's user based - every user has its own login keychain
2. it's not accessible by other users
3. it's encrypted with a key generated from your account password

The file system approach has #1 and #2 benefits from above, however it doesn't have #3, so keychain is the way to go. As regarding the keys, I'd recommend storing the private one in keychain, and the public one in user defauls (less secure, but anyway you'll distribute that key).
More about keychains:
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/756/how-secure-is-keychain-on-os-x 
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53579/how-is-the-system-keychain-secured-in-os-x (this more more about the system keychain, not the login one)